# How do I get tkinter scale widget to set it's upper limit to an updated variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to set the 'to=' configuration option on a tkinter scale widget. I want to take the user input from an entry widget and use it as the upper limit on the scale.

The way I have it set up now, the scale just stays stuck at 0 after the user enters a value in the entry box and clicks the button. The 'to=' configuration option doesn't seem to update after the user changes the variable.

How do I get the scale widget to set it's upper limit to the new value?

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter

class HomePage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x300')

        self.entry_value = tkinter.IntVar()

        self.entry_box = tkinter.Entry(master=self.root)
        self.entry_box.pack(pady=10)

        self.button = tkinter.Button(master=self.root, text='get value', command=self.set_value)

        self.button.pack(pady=10)

        self.scale = tkinter.Scale(master=self.root, from_=0, to=self.entry_value.get(), orient='horizontal')
        self.scale.pack(pady=10)

        self.show_entry_value = tkinter.Button(self.root, text='Updated Value',
                                               command=lambda: print(self.entry_value.get()))
        self.show_entry_value.pack()

    def set_value(self):
        self.entry_value.set(self.entry_box.get())


app = HomePage()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `configure` method to change the value:

```
self.scale.configure(to=the_new_value)
```

Comment: It works! I put that line into the method and it works. Thanks